# What is the best possible way to pass a Mulitline String as function argument?

Tags: javascript

What will be the Best practice to pass Multiline String as a Javascript function's argument.

Comment: Why can't you pass it as any variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it a variable!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript strings can contain newline characters, so you don't have to do anything special. (**Edit** Actually, I suppose you do — you have to use an escape sequence; that's covered below.) Example:

```
var s = "This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3.";
alert(s);
```

...alerts

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

The full syntax of the escape sequences in JavaScript strings is (of course) in the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), but here's a brief (probably incomplete) rundown:

- `\n` - newline
- `\r` - carriage return
- `\t` - tab
- `\v` - vertical tab
- `\b` - backspace
- `\f` - formfeed
- `\u0100` - Unicode character 256 (e.g., the value is in hex, four digits)
- `\xfd` - Unicode character 253 (e.g., the value is in hex, two digits)
- `\\` - backslash
- `\"` - double quote (useful when you're using double quotes to delimit a string literal)
- `\'` - single quote (useful when you're using single quotes to delimit a string literal)